# Is it possible to pass these parameters to Quickbooks, using command prompt?

Tags: command-line, parameters, quickbooks

I am trying to design an automated process for getting certain data from QuickBooks, and need it to open a specific company file, not ask me which one i want to select.

Is there a way to do this using a command prompt line? I've tried:

(program full path) + " " + (company file full path)

This option makes QB pop up saying i passed it invalid parameters. I have looked for a solution to this all over, but there seems to be no clear answers. Thank you!

By the way, using 2014 enterprise version if it makes any difference!

Comment: You need to start and end the company file full path with quotes `"""" & FilePath & """"` (VB) or `"\"" + FilePath + "\""` (C#)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the QuickBooks SDK to connect to QuickBooks will allow you to specify which company you want to interact with, but does not cause it to be display on the screen. The SDK is designed more for importing/exporting data from QuickBooks into a custom program. From what I understand of your question, you seem to want to automate the opening of QuickBooks files for the user.

I don't think that the QuickBooks executable is able to handle command line parameters (or if it is, I've never seen or heard of them). In the newer versions of QuickBooks, there's an application that gets installed to better allow opening of company files (.qbw) by double clicking them. It's called the QuickBooks Launcher and is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks\QBLaunch.exe. This application can take a company file parameter to open QuickBooks with the specified company file.

There are a few things to keep in mind, however.

First, only one instance of QuickBooks can be open on a computer at a time. This means that if CompanyA is open in QuickBooks, you can not open CompanyB without closing CompanyA. You will get a message "Problem: QuickBooks could not be started because it is already running the maximum number of instances".

Second, in newer versions of QuickBooks Accountant Edition and QuickBooks Enterprise, opening a second company file will open a second LIMITED instance of the QuickBooks software. You can read about the limitations here: http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/INF12879

Finally, there is not a way that I know of to use command lines to close an open QuickBooks file.

Comment: I found out that i can just use a feature in my program that runs the individual company file. Doing this, windows handles opening quickbooks appropriately, and it functions identically to double clicking the company file. This works for my use! However, good to know that calling QB with params wont likely work, thank you!

Comment: At least one piece of information above is wrong, when it says QB can't take command line parameters. This is corrected by David Murdoch's answer below. I used Murdoch's syntax in a Windows shortcut, and it works. However, Hpjchobbes is right when he says QB won't allow multiple instances. When I had a company open and clicked on the shortcut for another, QB warned me that it would have to close the open one in order to open the other. (This is with an old version: QB 99.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

> QBW32.exe -QFM "{Full Path To Your QuickBooks File Here}"

Comment: Confirmed that this works in QB 99. See my comment on Hpjchobbes' answer above.